# Web Api action method is not invoked

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have ajax request on page, which invoke Web Api method in my ASP.NET application.

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "/api/Book/GetBook",
    type: "GET",       
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
});
request.done(function (msg) {
    alert(msg);
});
request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
});
```

Source of api method:

```
   [HttpGet]
   public IEnumerable<PageViewModel> GetBook()
    {
        return _librarian.GiveBook(_authProvider.GetUserAccount());
    }
```

While debugging, action method has not invoke, and textStatus is "erorr".

Comment: _erorr_ or _error_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Web API was designed to be RESTful, part of accomplishing a RESTful interface is having an interface that identifies *resources* as the endpoints rather than CRUD operations. For example, you have a `Book` controller (which means `Book` is the resource) therefore if you want to pull a particular book down the URL would most likely be

```
/api/book/{bookId}
```

The default routing table is clever enough to map the HTTP verb to the relevant action in the controller.

Comment: I did change controller according yours recomendation http://pastebin.com/epzLxk64, and reqwest url - "/api/BookApi", but still dont work.

Comment: @Aminion what error do you get back? Does it reach the API? "*doesn't work*" isn't very helpful...

Comment: >_what error do you get back_ -string "error". _Does it reach the API_ - no, it dont. But! If I type the link in browser, it return me some file (my data in json, I think), but IE says - bookapi couldn`t  download.

Comment: @Aminion so that tells me that the API is fine, it's your jQuery that's the problem. Can you post your code? You can use a HTTP debugger like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect your requests to make sure they are correct.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PdXY5S4j This is full code. I tried a Fidder, but I can not accurately determine if all okay.

Comment: @Aminion try `$.get('/api/BookApi', function(book) { ... })`. I suspect the issue is with the JS request you are building via `$.ajax`.

Comment: Finally, I find the problem. Http code was 401(Unauthorized). Because I use [Authorize] attribute for controller. But, user has been authorized, before calling API.

Comment: @Aminion if the API requires authentication then you need to take that into consideration when building your client request, you will most likely need to pass the relevant authentication details in the header of the request or from some other means. Regardless, this is now beyond the scope of the question so if the 401 was the cause of the original problem then I suggest you just close the question and start a new one.

Comment: I forgot the [Authorize] attribute in controller which produce html for page,then user was not authorized on API call. Many thanks.